# nesting three level deep resource in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested, resources

I have three level deep nesting resources such as parent, child, comment

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :parents do
    resources :children do
      resources :grand_children
    end
  end
end
```

In action `grand_children#new` it alert the "parent must exist" 
could anyone help me how to create a grand_children nested in three level deep ?

Comment: GrandChildrenController#new should have `@grand_children = Parent.find(params[:parent_id]).children.find(params[:children_id]).grand_children.new`, same for the create action (use the same chain of nesting) and even for the show/edit actions, as you should not be able to see GrandChildren #2 with URL `/parents/1/children/1/grand_children/2` if GrandChildren parent's id is not 1 or GrandChildren's Children id is not 1. This prevent from basic URL manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

In your `GrandChildren` model you could have `belongs_to :child, optional: true`, but I'm not sure that will resolve your routing error, as nesting the route requires for the parent to exist.

Perhaps the solution instead is for your `grand_children#new` action to ensure a parent `child` exists, and the foreign key `child_id` is passed in on the creation of a `grand_child` record.